# Creating a vertically and horizontally centered html div

Tags: css, centering

I am trying to create a page similar to Google's homepage. It is to have a centrally located input box and a div on top of the page displaying links. I also want the page to resize itself dynamically if I change the size of the browser window. I have achieved partial success using yui2 grid css and a table. Here's a snippet:

```
<body>
  <div id="doc3">
    <div id="hd"><a style="float:left" href="link1.com"> link1</div> 
    <div id="bd" style="display: table; height: 400px;">
      <div style="display: display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle">
        <input name="searchbox" value="searchinput" size="40" />
        <input name="submit" type="submit" value="search />
      </div>
    </div> 
  </div>
</body>
```

The only issue with this html is that the page doesn't dynamically resize upon resizing the browser window. Is there a better way of doing this ?

Comment: I was surprised to observe that Google uses the `<center>` tag to effect their horizontal centering. This seems odd to me, given their leadership in other areas ...

Comment: Yeah, I have observed that too. I would prefer to avoid it as it has been deprecated. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_center.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use jQuery to set it to perfectly.

### jQuery

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var wh = (($(window).height()-$('#center').height())/2)+'px';
    var ww = (($(window).width()-$('#center').width())/2)+'px';
    $('#center').css({
        top: wh,
        left: ww
    });
}).resize();
```

### CSS

```
#center {
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: absolute;
    width: 50px;
}​
```

If you don't care about *perfectly* vertically centered, you could do:

```
#center {
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 50px;
    top: 45%; /* or whatever % looks 'right' */
}​
```